# How can I make this into a better graph?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, data-science

I need help in transforming this graph into something more presentable and readable? Any tips/help would be much appreciated!

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(df_date_count.index, df_date_count["customer_id"], c="black", label = "Customer ID")
plt.plot(df_date_count.index, np.linspace(trans_vol,trans_vol,n_points), c="r", label = "Mean transaction volume")
plt.title("ANZ Transaction Volume vs. Date")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Number of customers")
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()[enter image description here][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume your complaint is about the x-axis' ticks and labels. As mentioned in another answer, you can use the ***dates*** from ***matplotlib***:

```
from matplotlib import dates as mdates
```

See the following link for more details:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.ConciseDateFormatter

Here is a code snippet you could add where you set your plot configurations:

```
#--------------------------------------
#Feel free to try different options
#--------------------------------------
#locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
locator = mdates.MonthLocator()

formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try changing the interval of your ticks

```
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator, DateFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y) #your data
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator(interval=3))
```

or maybe the rotation:

```
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelrotation=45)
```

or even the date formatting:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%m'))
```

or font settings etc.. make the figure bigger